# Can't access elements of merged arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

So I had 2 objects that need to work together, one idea that was given to me was to merge them. Did that, using `array_merge`
But now I can't access the second object from the merged one and I'm stuck. The keys that appear after merge look a little weird, have I used it wrongly?

```
$merged=array_merge_recursive((array)$post,(array)$image);
```

And the `var_dump` for `$merged` shows me this:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    object(Models\Post)[7]
      protected 'id' => string '17' (length=2)
      protected 'title' => string 'qwq' (length=3)
      protected 'body' => string 'wqwq' (length=4)
      protected 'views' => string '22' (length=2)
      protected 'imgId' => string '17' (length=2)
      protected '_attr_accessible' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'title' (length=5)
          1 => string 'body' (length=4)
          2 => string 'views' (length=5)
      protected '_validators' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_errors' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_valid' => boolean true
  '�*�id' => string '17' (length=2)
  '�*�path' => string '/media/' (length=7)
  '�*�name' => string 'col_right_callout.jpg' (length=21)
  '�*�idPost' => string '0' (length=1)
  '�*�description' => string 'wqeqw' (length=5)
  '�*�_attr_accessible' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'name' (length=4)
      1 => string 'path' (length=4)
      2 => string 'description' (length=11)
  '�*�_validators' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '�*�_errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '�*�_valid' => boolean true
```

How do I access the path or any field from the second part of the array?
Content of `$post`

```
array (size=1)   0 => 
    object(Models\Post)[7]
      protected 'id' => string '17' (length=2)
      protected 'title' => string 'qwq' (length=3)
      protected 'body' => string 'wqwq' (length=4)
      protected 'views' => string '23' (length=2)
      protected 'imgId' => string '17' (length=2)
      protected '_attr_accessible' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'title' (length=5)
          1 => string 'body' (length=4)
          2 => string 'views' (length=5)
      protected '_validators' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_errors' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_valid' => boolean true
```

Content of `$image`

```
object(Models\Image)[9]
  protected 'id' => string '17' (length=2)
  protected 'path' => string '/media/' (length=7)
  protected 'name' => string 'col_right_callout.jpg' (length=21)
  protected 'idPost' => string '0' (length=1)
  protected 'description' => string 'wqeqw' (length=5)
  protected '_attr_accessible' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'name' (length=4)
      1 => string 'path' (length=4)
      2 => string 'description' (length=11)
  protected '_validators' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_valid' => boolean true
```

Comment: Can you add the content of `$post` and `$image` please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because image is object, protected and private properties have special character prepended when you cast object to array.

With post you are casting array to array. If you do something like (array)$post[0] you will get same issue with both objects.

Take a look how to get array out of it: [How to convert (cast) Object to Array without Class Name prefix in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847751/how-to-convert-cast-object-to-array-without-class-name-prefix-in-php)